# REST mapping to GraphQL

Tags: node.js, rest, graphql

We are currently developing an online shop for products in node.js. We use GraphQL in our backend. Now we would like to offer REST for our customers in addition to GraphQL. What would be the fastest and most effective solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

When designing REST APIs one should start from database tables aka persistent entities and there are too many ways and frameworks.

When you have GraphQL already in place you may want your REST API to be somewhat similar, but I bet that made things more complicated, while pure REST evolved as simple HTTP implementation.

In face HTTP standard and REST standard have the same author(s).